# Two consecutive yields, only the first work

Tags: scrapy

I have this piece of code that only executes the first yield's callback and not the next one. I have tried reordering them and it gives the same result: 
Only the first yield callback gets executed.

```
    for j in range(totalOrderPages):  # the code gets in the loop
        productURI = feedUrl % (productId, j + 1)
        print "Got in the loop" # this gets printed 
        yield response.follow(productURI, self.parse_orders, meta={'pid': productId, 'categories': categories})
    yield response.follow(first_page, self.parse_product, meta={'pid': productId, 'categories': categories})
```

Is there anything in Python or scrapy that prevents 2 consecutive yields?

Second question: 
I'm trying to debug this using pdb.set_trace() but when I try to execute yield from the debugging console, it give the `yield outside function` error.

Does anyone know how can we debug yields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more details, like the redirection behaviour of the specific site or the contents of the variables (`feedUrl`, `productURI`, `first_page`, etc), I would say that some requests are being dropped by the Dupefilter (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class).
I'd recommend you to enable the `DEBUG` logging level and setting [`DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=True`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-debug), and check the logs to see if that's the case.
You can force requests to bypass the Dupefilter by adding `dont_filter=True` when calling `response.follow`.

If this doesn't solve your issue, please share your crawl logs so we can have more information to debug the issue. Happy scraping!